# Retrofit 2 query (client_id) and parameter (song title)

Tags: interface, retrofit, soundcloud

How to write a retrofit interface that accepts a key (String) and then "&q=" and my SONG (String)? That's what I did:

```
public interface API {
    @GET("/tracks")
    Call<List<Song>> getSongs(@Query("client_id") String id,
                              @Path("query") String query);
}
```

and in the activity:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .build();
    API service = retrofit.create(API.class);
    Call<List<Song>> call = service.getSongs("nofx");
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Song>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Song>> call, Response<List<Song>> response) {
            List<Song> songList = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Song>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
```

URI:

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?client_id=MY_KEY&q=SONG
```

Answer (score 0):

The `client_id` and `q` params in the URL that you posted are both path params. So your interface method should look something like this:

```
public interface API {
    @GET("tracks")
    Call<List<Song>> getSongs(@Path("client_id") String id,
                              @Path("q") String query);
}
```

I also recommend moving the prepended forward slash on "/tracks" to the end of your `Constants.BASE_URL` so that you do not have to add the forward slash to all of your API methods.

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer! I get: com.sun.jdi.internalExecption: Unexpected JDWP error: 103 on this line:  Call<List<Song>> call = service.getSongs(Constants.CLIENT_ID, "nofx");

Comment: I've never seen that error before. Is this error displayed when debugging or running your app (or both)? What IDE and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

into manifest file.